# Why do objects use hash tables instead of just being declared using 'class'

Tags: javascript

I'm coming from Python and getting pretty good at JS. Everything is easy so far except object declaration. Making objects using key-value pairs seems so cumbersome and confusing.

What is the point of this?

EDIT:
My idea of a javascript object is this:

```
var person = {firstname:"John", lastname:"Doe", age:50, eyecolor:"blue"};
```

It appears as though that is only one form of an object though.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of what you mean in js and the corresponding code in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Most OO languages implement objects as something very much like a hash table, js just makes that explicit.
2. Is using key value pairs that much more different and more work than creating a class? A class is just a function for creating a closure over some variables. This pattern became popular and so people started to bake it into languages.
3. Ecmascript 6 includes adding classes:

http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/use-ecmascript-6-today--net-31582#class

see @maerics code above. Maybe you are doing it wrong (there are several ways to get OO behavior in js).

Comment: Are you certain about #1? In many OO languages, fields are a constant memory offset away from the start of the object and thus no hash function is needed - faster for lookup.

Comment: Quote "something very much like a hash table". How do you think they map the method name or field name to the offset? A hashtable simply hashes an object (e.g. a string) into an int, that is then converted into a memory offset.

Comment: Well okay, in OO languages like Ruby or Python there probably is a hash table-like structure somewhere behind the scenes (although they are slow and use extra memory, so avoided as much as possible in implementations). But in many OO languages, like Java, C++, and I assume C#, they wouldn't be used AFAIK - the offsets are computed at compile time. And in these cases, using a hash, table, map, whatever it's called would be worse in many cases.

Comment: Again quote "something very much like a hash table". I did not say they all use a hash table. But hashing to a memory offset is very similar.

Comment: Simon - it's not about whether what you said was technically 'wrong' or 'right'! That's a moot and unimportant debate. All I'm getting at is simply that in many OO languages, accessing a field of an object is much much faster than a hash table lookup which is important to know and is unclear in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

**[Edit]**

The choice to make objects associative arrays was an explicit one; presumably because in some cases it is convenient to create objects/structures on-the-fly instead of conforming to a predefined "class".

This "loose typing" also allows you to create reusable code based on the *properties* of an object rather than its *type*.

**[Original]**

> Everything is easy so far except object declaration. Making objects using key-value pairs seems so cumbersome and confusing.

I dunno, seems pretty easy to me...

```
function Person(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}

var joe = new Person('Joe', 10);
joe.name; // => "Joe"
joe.age;  // => 10
```

The choice of "prototypal inheritance" instead of "classical inheritance" was deliberate (for better or worse); it's just a different way of doing things with its own pros and cons.

Comment: I was referring to something like this: my_obj = {make_person:person()};